# How do you get the object in the array to read it as toUpperCase?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

This function works without the .toUpperCase method. But I want to get it to work with the toUpperCase. What do I do? I am currently learning Javascript from a udemy course:

```
const notes = [
    {},{
    title: 'My next trip',
    body: 'I would like to go to Spain'
}, {
    title: 'Habbits to work on',
    body: 'Excercise, Eat a bit better'
}, {
    title: 'Office modification',
    body: 'Get a new seat'
}]


function findNote(notes, noteTitle){
    const index = notes.findIndex(function(item, index){
        return item.title.toUpperCase() === noteTitle.toUpperCase()
    })

    return notes[index]
}

const note = findNote(notes, 'Office modification')
console.log(note)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided no error logs, I can only guess at what's wrong: you got a `RefernceError` in the callback. If that's the case, here is why:

```js
const notes = [
    {},{
```

notice you have an empty object in the array `notes`, and `title` in `item.title.toUpperCase()` evaluates to `undefined` which causes a `ReferenceError`, simply removing the empty object will fix this problem.

The reason it works without `toUpperCase` is because there is no dereferencing `title`, you are just using === on it which doesn't care if it's `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add check whether your object of an `notes` array has property `title`. It can be check using [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
if (fooObject.hasOwnProperty('title'))
```

or in your case:

```
item.hasOwnProperty('title')
```

However, we want to find cases where `title` key does not exist and omit such objects, because if there is no `title`, it means there is no method `toUpperCase()`. So it can be checked with operator `!`(NOT):

```
if (!item.title) // `NOT` + undefined gives `true`
    return false;
```

So the whole code looks like this:

```js
const notes = [
  {},
  {
      title: 'My next trip',
      body: 'I would like to go to Spain'
  },
  {
      title: 'Habbits to work on',
      body: 'Excercise, Eat a bit better'
  },
  {
      title: 'Office modification',
      body: 'Get a new seat'
  }
]


function findNote(notes, noteTitle) {
  const index = notes.findIndex(function (item, index) {
    if (!item.title)
      return false;

    return item.title.toUpperCase() === noteTitle.toUpperCase()
  })
  return notes[index]
}

const note = findNote(notes, 'Office modification')
console.log(note)
```